# Is possible to add a python path with pipenv?

Tags: virtualenv, buildout, pipenv

I have some old python projects that are NOT packaged (no setup.py) I need to access them.
Till now I was using buildout where I can specify a python path in buildout.cfg.
I would like to switch to pipenv : how can I specify an arbitrary python path with pipenv so I can import my unpackaged projects ?

Comment: You can’t. Pipenv builds around pip, which builds around setup.py. There’s no way around it.

Comment: Hello [Eric](https://stackoverflow.com/users/755371/eric).

Do this one answer you?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49699244/customize-module-search-path-pythonpath-via-pipenv

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Customize module search path (PYTHONPATH) via pipenv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49699244/customize-module-search-path-pythonpath-via-pipenv)

Answer (score 0):

I finally wrote a script that creates a .pth file with all the pythonpath I wanted to add in the virtualenv:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from distutils import sysconfig
import os
site_packages_path = sysconfig.get_python_lib()

PTH_FILENAME = 'MyApp.pth'
# Change here to your project home dir
PROJECT_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))

relative_paths = [
  '.',
  'plugins',
  'src/achilterm',
  'src/addicted',
  'src/naghelp',
  'src/textops',
  'src',
]

absolute_paths = [ os.path.join(PROJECT_DIR,p) for p in relative_paths ]

with open(os.path.join(site_packages_path,PTH_FILENAME),'w') as fh:
    for p in absolute_paths:
        print 'Installing path : %s ...' % p
        fh.write('%s\n' % p)
```