# Handle imports and Pythonpath with Pipenv

Tags: python, pycharm, python-import, pipenv

**File tree**:

```
/path/to/project/root/ 
├── .git/ 
├── Pipfile 
├── Pipfile.lock 
├── __init__.py 
└── package1
    ├── __init__.py
    ├── src
    │   ├── __init__.py
    │   ├── external_lib
    │       └── packageX
    │           ├── packageY
    │           └── packageZ
    │   ├── foo.py
    │   ├── bar.py
```

**Constraints:**

- `foo.py` imports `bar.py`
- both `foo.py` and `bar.py` import some files from `external_lib/packageX/packageZ`
- files in `external_lib/packageX/packageZ` require `packageX` and `packageY` to be in the `PYTHONPATH` for their own includes.
- I don't have a single entry point: sometimes I want to launch `foo.py`, sometimes `bar.py`.
- external_lib is external, it's a git submodule. I don't want to change its content.
- This is a shared project, I'd like a solution that's included in the git repository...

**What I'm doing right now**

I'm following the advice given [here](http://sametmax.com/les-imports-en-python/) (in French though), that claims to be good practice:

- Before running any script, I run `cd package1/src/external_lib/packageX; export PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:`pwd`:`pwd`/packageY; cd ../../../..`
- All my imports are written like this: `import package1.src.bar`,  `import package1.src.external_lib.packageX.packageZ.some_module`
- I always call all scripts from the project root.

This gives something like this:

```
cd /path/to/project/root/ 
pipenv shell
cd package1/src/external_lib/packageX; export PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:`pwd`:`pwd`/packageY; cd ../../../..
python package1/src/foo.py
python package1/src/bar.py
```

**Question**

What is the best practice, in terms of project architecture, Pipenv use, import writing, etc., to manage all the imports smoothly, with a minimum amount of manual actions and constraints (such as `export PYTHONPATH=...` commands before running scripts and launching the scripts from the root), in the most Pythonic and Pipenv-ic way ?

Ideally I'd also like Pycharm to be able to get all the imports correctly without further manual settings, so that what I do in Pycharm reflects what would happen from a terminal.

One possible solution I've seen is to use Pipenv's `.env` file, to add the `export PYTHONPATH=...` in it, and rely on its [automatic loading](https://github.com/pypa/pipenv/blob/master/docs/advanced.rst#-automatic-loading-of-env). However, apparently this file [is not meant for that and should not be commited](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49699244/7456923).

Comment: If you are using Python3 and if `external_lib` comes with expected `__init__.py` files you should just have to use abolute path imports (`import package1.src.external_lib.packageX`) anywhere in your code and it gonna works (until you don't make recursive imports) + It's the first time I heard that updating PYTHONPATH is a good practice. I always seen it as a dirty hack..

Comment: 2 more cents, since your external_lib is external, if it brings a `setup.py` you may enjoy to install it with Pip like any lib instead of shipping it with your code (for a lot of reasons), if it does not brings a `setup.py` and it's free software just push a PR for this.

Comment: Thanks for the reply ! external_lib is the [tensorflow/models repo](https://github.com/tensorflow/models), in which I want to use the object detection API. Its [installation guide](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/g3doc/installation.md) is what told me to update the PYTHONPATH. There is no overall `__init__.py` or `setup.py`, but there is a `setup.py` in the research (packageX) folder , so I'll try to install it with pip !