# Modifying PYTHONPATH using .env files with Pipenv

Tags: python, environment-variables, pythonpath, pipenv

I'm trying to add a project directory to the `PYTHONPATH` using `pipenv`. Following the hint of [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49699244/customize-module-search-path-pythonpath-via-pipenv), I created a [`.env`](https://github.com/pypa/pipenv/blob/master/docs/advanced.rst#-automatic-loading-of-env) file in order to modify the path used by the virtualenv managed by `pipenv`.

I created the `.env` file (in `/foo/bar/myProject`) as follows:

```
PYTHONPATH=${PYTHONPATH}:${PWD}
```

but when I activate the virtualenv, this is the new path:

```
$ python -c "import sys; print(sys.path)"
['', '/foo/bar/${PYTHONPATH}', '/foo/bar/${PWD}', '/foo/bar/myProject',...]
```

It correctly adds `/foo/bar/myProject` to the `PYTHONPATH`. However, looks like it adds also two extra entries with unsubstituted environment variables.

Why does it happen and how can I avoid this?

Note: I'm using the Z shell (probably it does not matter).

Answer (score 4):

You probably don't have the `$PYTHONPATH` envariable set in your shell, so `pipenv` stupidly replaces `${PYTHONPATH}` with the value in the `.env` file (i.e. `${PYTHONPATH}:${PWD}`). Then `${PWD}` is successfully expanded, giving you the final value `PYTHONPATH=${PYTHONPATH}:${PWD}:/foo/bar/myProject`. That leads to the weird looking `sys.path`. You can fix the issue by omitting `${PYTHONPATH}` from the value:

```
PYTHONPATH=${PWD}
```

or set it to some value before running `pipenv`:

```
export PYTHONPATH=/path/to/dir
pipenv shell
```

Tested with `pipenv` version 2018.11.26.